# Angular element.html() event bind

Tags: angularjs

I need some operation like this:
user selects a html template, then the html will be injected by `element.html('<span>A</span><span>B</span>....')` in a directive.
i want to bind click event for all spans.
if i write like this `element.html('<span ng-click="action()">A</span>')`, this doesn`t work.
my question is how to bind event for those spans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$compile` for Angular to recognize it:

```
element.html(
    $compile('<span ng-click="action()">A</span>')(scope)
);
```

Comment: awesome! it works ^_^， but i use element.append instead of element.html